# Convert string parameter to object type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following code:

```
public ActionResult GenericActionForSomething(string objectType)
    {
        switch (objectType)
        {
            case "Business":
                // Do Something with object here, like save
                _db.Create<Business>();
                break;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

How can I convert a string parameter to an object? For this example I need to convert the parameter "objectType" into an object of type "Business".  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at reflection and dynamic class instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate an object based on its type name by using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx). For that particular overload of the method you need to supply the assembly name as well; for this you may find useful the [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) class' [GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) and [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one single way to do this. If your `Business` class has a constructor which accepts `string`, you can invoke that. If it has an explicit conversion operator, you can use it as well. If it has an associated `TypeConverter`, use that too.

Your question is way too broad.

Comment: I guess he wants to instantiate object of objectType class

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you might be wanting to do model binding to your action, like:

```
public ViewResult NewBusiness(Business business)
{
    _db.Create<Business>(business);
    return View();
}
```

Read a general overview of [model binding in this article](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying to make a a more generic way of doing model binding where I don't have to pass in a specific object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection to achieve this.
You can either use `Activator.CreateInstance(className)` method or you can first load the Assemply containing your type and then call CreateInstance() method like this:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
Object obj = assem.CreateInstance(className);
```